# Tableau connecting to Snowflake using Key-Pair authentication

Tags: tableau-api, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

> I'm trying to connect tableau to Snowflake using the Key-pair authentication method. I have generated the keys and associated it with the user. I'm looking for some guidance as how can I configure it on Tableau to use those keys for login to snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

Tableau's Snowflake connector does not currently support key-pair authentication.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's possible by specifying additional parameters:
[Tableau - Snowflake key-pair authentication](https://www.biztory.com/blog/tableau-snowflake-key-pair-authentication)

Comment: please edit you answer to give precise results. wich parameters?